# Twilio Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 401] Unable to fetch record:

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api

Am trying to Fetch a Queue resource on twilio i want to get the current_size (queue size)

am using PHP code below

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid    = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$queue = $twilio->queues("QUXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
                ->fetch();

print($queue->friendlyName);
```

but i keep getting this error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Twilio\Exceptions\RestException: [HTTP 401] Unable to fetch record: Authentication Error - invalid username in C:\xampp\htdocs\calls\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Version.php:86 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\calls\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Version.php(111): Twilio\Version->exception(Object(Twilio\Http\Response), 'Unable to fetch...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\calls\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\QueueContext.php(51): Twilio\Version->fetch('GET', '/Accounts/AP726...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\calls\agent\incoming.php(22): Twilio\Rest\Api\V2010\Account\QueueContext->fetch() #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\calls\vendor\twilio\sdk\src\Twilio\Version.php on line 86
```

any solution how to fix this? and or get the current queue size

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you able to successfully execute a curl query from the Twilio API explorer, or from your machine to fetch the same information?

> https://www.twilio.com/console/api-explorer/voice/queues/read

This error seems to be caused by passing an invalid SID.

Comment: Yes with curl it works on this link https://www.twilio.com/console/api-explorer/voice/queues/read  i will try to create a function for curl to get the queues.

Comment: Can you help me turn this ```curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{accountSid}/Queues.json' -u accountSid:[AuthToken];``` into php curl i created this function with curl but i don't know how to use it ```function getQueueSize(){
    $url = '';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $head = curl_exec($ch);
    $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);
die($head)
}```

Comment: Set 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{accountSid}/Queues.json' as your curl url variable:
$url = 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/ASxxxxxxxxxxx/Queues.json' 

@tp45, rather can you verify the correct $sid is used in the original code snippet?

Comment: The curl solved my problem, i took this curl ```curl 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/{accountSid}/Queues.json' -u accountSid:[AuthToken];``` converted it into php curl with this ```https://incarnate.github.io/curl-to-php/``` now it works. Thank you @TTA a lot